# Generic is generalised to a string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function, which can be simplified to the example below:

```
type Delegate<Key extends "firstKey" | "secondKey"> = {
  key: Key;
  deleteMany: (where: { where: { [n in Key]: string } }) => Promise<unknown>;
};

const removeDuplicatesGeneric = <Key extends "firstKey" | "secondKey">(
  delegate: Delegate<Key>
) => {
  delegate.deleteMany({ where: { [delegate.key]: 'key' } });
};
```

As `key` is of the type `Key`, I expect it to not cause issues when passing to `where`. TypeScript shows me an error though:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [n in Key]: string; }'.
```

Any ideas why `[delegate.key]` is interpreted as `x: string` instead of `x: Key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design.
Because `string` type is much wider than `"firstKey" | "secondKey"` you are getting an error.

In this case, it is ok to use type assertion:

```js
type Delegate<Key extends "firstKey" | "secondKey"> = {
    key: Key;
    deleteMany: (arg: { where: Record<Key, string> }) => Promise<unknown>;
};

const record = <
    Key extends PropertyKey,
    Value
>(key: Key, value: Value) =>
    ({ [key]: value }) as Record<Key, Value>

const removeDuplicatesGeneric = <Key extends "firstKey" | "secondKey">(
    delegate: Delegate<Key>
) => {
    delegate.deleteMany({ where: record(delegate.key, 'key') });
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGV59m)